# Batch Store WMIC Query with multiple conditions into variable

Tags: batch-file, scripting, wmi-query, wmic

I am using this line in a batch script which successfully stores a user's SID value into a variable called SID

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%s IN ('wmic path win32_useraccount where name^='%_curruser%' get sid /value ^| find /i "SID"') DO SET SID=%%t
```

I'd like to modify this to include an "AND" in the WMIC Query but I can't seem to get it to work.

The correct query is:

```
wmic path win32_useraccount where "name='%USERNAME%' and Domain like 'HB%'" GET SID /VALUE
```

Can someone please help me translate this so the SID value is stored into a variable?

Comment: Please also note that `DOS` is the OS from the 1980/1990s, and I don't think you are using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape the `%` percent character](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in `Domain like 'HB%'` by doubling it as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%s IN ('
    wmic path win32_useraccount where "name='%USERNAME%' and Domain like 'HB%%'" GET SID /VALUE ^| find /i "SID"
') DO for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%%t") do SET "SID=%%i"
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%s` to retrieve the `SID` value;
- `%%i` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour): each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (CR+CR+LF) instead of common `0x0D0A` (CR+LF).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and helpful link